# What is your experience switching from TeXShop to Sublime Text?

Tags: editors, texshop, sublime-text

I recently installed Sublime Text 3 on my mac and spent a couple of hours reading the doc and installing `LaTeX` tools. So far my long-time editor has been `TeXShop`, I have a number of text-expansion tricks that help my workflow quite a bit. I imagine, although I could be wrong, that switching to ST would be a step up once the learning curve is behind me, but I hesitate putting the required time/effort, mainly because I have no idea how much of an improvement that would be (and I understand that I would loose the sync-back pdf->tex from Skim to the editor).

So far most of my editing is for `LaTeX` source, so I have close to no experience with real programmer's editors (emacs, vi and others), although I tried emacs a couple of times and gave up. Once in a while I use TextWrangler for grep-based search/replace. I do very little programming, so the main reason to learn ST would be for `LaTeX`.

So my question goes to those who have **actually** attempted to switch, with or without success.

1. How long did it take to you to be as efficient with ST as you were with TeXShop?
2. Did you gain things that were not obvious to you from just reading about ST?
3. Any particular recommendations?
4. If you failed, gave up or switched back, why was that?

Thanks !

Comment: Hi there. I'm afraid that this is solely asking for people's opinions,  which is unsuitable on a question-and-answer site. You may have a better chance on a standard forum such as [LaTeX Community](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/).

Comment: Or you could ask in the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends)!

Comment: @yo' Not a question about opinion but rather about real experience. You could conceive subquestion 2 as opinion -- I do not -- and 1/3/4 are clearly not opinion related. I am NOT asking which is best between TS and ST. Anyway, I can rephrase 2 a bit.

Comment: @JosephWright Your are right. Still, after searching on the subject quite a bit on the web and finding very little, I tend to think this deserves a question here.

Comment: @A.G. Maybe there is misunderstanding about "opinion-based". The answer to the question "how long" or "did you" depends in this case so much on who is answering that it can't be answered objectively.

Comment: @yo' Yes, there is definitely a misunderstanding. "How long" and "did you" are indeed objective questions and have little to do with "opinion". Opinion would be "Did you think it was too long?". There is a difference between "opinion" and "personal experience"... In my opinion the belief that all non-technical questions are opinion based is too narrow.

Comment: If a question is "likely to generate opinion-based answers" that does not mean that it explicitly asks for opinions. The job of moderators should be to make sure that opinion-based answers to non-opinion questions are regulated, not to remove any question that might attract, among perfectly fine answers, a few opinions.

Comment: @A.G. Sorry, I really lose your argumentation here. I state it IMHO clearly -- _it can't be answered objectively_ -- and I stand behind this statement. Also, questions "what experience you have with ..." are in the same category (fine on forums, not fine on here). (From my point of view, this discussion lost any purpose. Anyways, if you want to discuss it further, you can visit [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends), where more people than just me can discuss this Q again).